# Best tools for Thick Client Penetration Testing

Tags: security, thickbox

I am looking for Application Security Testing (Penetration Testing) of Thick Client Applications. I know of Echo Mirage and ITR as good tools to test these kinda applications.

Does anyone know of any other tools that do this?

Answer (score 0):

Echo Mirage is a greater starter on Thick Clients. Introduced to this by the (smart) bloke who wrote it. It works around dll injection.

What's the context?

It becomes extremely useful on a Thick Client which is leaking info it shouldn't (and using logic built into the client side). This was then used to own a Database /App.